# Unnecessary styles loaded in all pages in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working in Rails 5. I have added active admin and other gems as well as styles. In the application.scss There are following statements

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "social-share-kit";
@import "trix";
@import "easy-autocomplete.min";
@import "easy-autocomplete.themes.min";
@import "dashboard";
```

My dashboard.scss file has some styles that override default bootstrap styles. Now the dashboard.css has been loaded in all pages of application and there are conflicts with other styles. Also, the active admin styles are even loading in home page which does not make any sense.

Is there some way so that I can render the styles only in that specific controller. For example dashboard.scss should only load in dashboard controller.

Comment: Not everything needs to use the same global layout... Create more than one?

Comment: thanks and how do I import that specific css? like this? <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'dashboard' %>

Comment: Yes. An application will typically use one layout for *most* of its pages, but you can choose to load a different (or no!) layout for specific controllers/actions. See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html